# How to wait two OnCreate Firebase Functions finished

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to wait until the second OnCreate its finished for trigger a notification. The thing is that the second OnCreate depends on the first OnCreate document.
Because I don't know the document id at "comida" until it is created in "Proveedores". Here is my database:
[image]

[image]
I want to trigger when a new document at "Pedidos" from that document id that is in "comida" is created.

This is what I have try:

```
export const newProveedorAdd = functions.firestore
    .document("Proveedores/{proveedorID}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
      const idProveedor = snapshot.id;
      const infoProveedor = snapshot.data();
      if (infoProveedor) {
        const RUC = infoProveedor.RUC;
        console.log("Proveedor nuevo id: " +idProveedor + " RUC: " + RUC);
        console.log("Ruta doc: "+"comida/"+idProveedor+"{proveedoID}/Pedidos/{pedidoID}");
        await functions.firestore
            .document("comida/"+idProveedor+"/Pedidos/{pedidoID}")
            .onCreate((snapshot) => {
              const numPedido = snapshot.id;
              console.log("ENTRO 2 " + numPedido);
              return Promise;
            });
      }
    });
```

This is also the console from Firebase Functions. It seems that is not waiting for the second OnCreate to finish

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Cloud Firestore `onCreate()` trigger within a triggered Cloud Function code which will not work. Because the [Cloud Firestore events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers) are intended to be used for Cloud Functions and it will only listen to an exported object of `functions.firestore`. Also one Cloud Function can listen to one trigger. So, for multiple triggers one has to use multiple Cloud Functions.

In your case you have a `Proveedores` collection and a `comida` collection. You want to trigger a Cloud Function when a document inside the `Proveedores` collection is created. Now again you also want to send notifications when a document is created inside the `Pedidos` subcollection which is inside the document having the document id same as that of the document in the `Proveedores` collection which was created earlier.

To implement the above I would suggest you use two Cloud Functions.

Function-1 is triggered when a document is created inside the `Proveedores` collection. Inside this Function you can create an empty document inside Pedidos subcollection, which is inside a document, having the document id same as the document created in the `Proveedores` collection, within the `comida` collection. When the document is created it will trigger Function-2 as it is created to listen to the `onCreate()` event on `comida/{comidaID}/Pedidos/{pedidosID}`, where the logic to send notification can be implemented.

Function : 1

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
const db=admin.firestore();
exports.newFunction = functions.firestore.
   document("Proveedores/{proveedorID}").onCreate((snapshot)=>{
     const idProveedor = snapshot.id;
     const infoProveedor = snapshot.data();
     if (infoProveedor) {
       const name = infoProveedor.name;
       console.log("Proveedor nuevo id: " +idProveedor + " Name: " + name);
       db.collection("comida").doc(idProveedor).
           collection("Pedidos").doc().set({});
     }
   });
```

Function : 2

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
// const db=admin.firestore();
exports.newFunction = functions.firestore.
   document("comida/{comidaID}/Pedidos/{pedidosID}").onCreate((snapshot)=>{
     const idPedidos = snapshot.id;
     console.log("The document has been created with document Id: "+idPedidos);
    // implement logic to send notifications here
   });
```